# How to make checkbox "Badge" in MaterialUI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

According to the API of Badge https://material-ui.com/api/badge/   there is a prop `component` which takes either a string to use a DOM element or a component.

In My code

```
<Badge color="primary" classes={{ badge: classes.badge }} component="checkbox">
  <Avatar className={classes.orangeAvatar}>AP</Avatar>
</Badge>
```

OR

```
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';

<Badge color="primary" classes={{ badge: classes.badge }} component={Checkbox}>
   <Avatar className={classes.orangeAvatar}>AP</Avatar>
</Badge>
```

In both the cases I am no getting checkbox as badge. How to do this?

Comment: What is the reason for you doing these? Do you want to just render checkbox? Otherwise your Avatar component might not be rendered.

Comment: I want to select people by clicking on the avatars.

Comment: It don't have to be complicated. Just use the Checkbox component. See answer below. Hope that helped.

Comment: Check this [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/71l1w08n8q) if the thing that do you need

Answer (score 1):

Use Checkbox component. You can use component for icon props when it is not checked and checkedIcon props when it is checked.

```js
      <Checkbox
          icon={<Avatar className={classes.purpleAvatar}> AP</Avatar>}
          checkedIcon={<Avatar className={classes.orangeAvatar}> AP</Avatar>}
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck on the same problem and worked out as below.

Use badgeContent property.
badgeContent property accepts node and shows it as a badge content.

```
import CheckIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Check'

<Badge
  color="secondary"
  anchorOrigin={{
    vertical: 'top',
    horizontal: 'right',
  }}
  badgeContent={<CheckIcon style={{ fontSize: 10, padding: 0, color: 'white' }} />}
  classes={{ badge: classes.badge }}
>
  <Avatar className={classes.orangeAvatar}>AP</Avatar>
</Badge>
```

After that you can customize that badge content style like this.

```
import { Badge } from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  badge: {
    fontSize: 30
  }
}));

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Badge
        badgeContent={"h"}
        color="secondary"
        classes={{ badge: classes.badge }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

In my case I used following style to change badge size.

```
  badge: {
    fontSize: 16,
    padding: 0,
    minWidth: '12px !important',
    height: '12px !important',
  },
```

More discussion about customization will be found [How to change font size of material ui badge content in reactjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66438741/how-to-change-font-size-of-material-ui-badge-content-in-reactjs).