# How to change font size of material ui badge content in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to change the font size of the label in material ui badge.
I am using `style={{ fontSize: "15" }}` but that only affect its child, which is an icon.

Code:

```
<Badge badgeContent={props.cartCount} color="secondary" style={{ fontSize: "15" }}>
    <ShoppingCart className={classes.mediumIcon} />
</Badge>
```

Comment: you can overwrite the .MuiBadge-dot class css. See the working copy https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-875uf?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ideal way would be use classes `badge` as mentioned in [documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/badge/)

```
import { Badge } from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import "./styles.css";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  badge: {
    fontSize: 30
  }
}));

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Badge
        badgeContent={"h"}
        color="secondary"
        classes={{ badge: classes.badge }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you use mui system then this can change badge font size

```
    <Badge
        badgeContent={9}
        color="error"
        overlap="circular"
        sx={{ "& .MuiBadge-badge": { fontSize: 9, height: 15, minWidth: 15 } }}
    >
        <IconButton sx={{ p: 0, color: "primary.main" }}>
            <Notifications />
        </IconButton>
    </Badge>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the font-size as below.
create styles of different font-size in `useStyles`

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  font1: {
    fontSize: "1rem"
  },
)}
```

And then assign it as below to the `Badge` component

```
<Badge
        classes={{
          badge: classes.font1
        }}
        badgeContent={99}
        {...defaultProps}
      />
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-9ldct?file=/demo.js:176-322)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the componentProps attribute as follows (this example changes the color of the text in the badge but the same principle will work for fontSize).

```
  <Badge badgeContent={comments}  componentsProps={{ root: {style: {color: 'white'}}  }}>
     <CommentIcon  />
  </Badge>
```